# How to fetch /data/anr/anr_xxx on Oreo (8.1.0)?

Tags: android, adb, android-anr-dialog

I'm unable to adb pull /data/anr/anr_xxx files on my Pixel Xl with Android 8.1.0.

My trials:

```
➜  Downloads adb shell ls -al /data/anr
total 1184
drwxrwxr-x  2 system system   4096 2018-06-24 13:57 .
drwxrwx--x 43 system system   4096 1970-02-11 19:30 ..
-rw-------  1 system system 503517 2018-06-24 01:41 anr_2018-06-24-01-41-39-700
-rw-------  1 system system 683519 2018-06-24 13:57 anr_2018-06-24-13-57-19-517
➜  Downloads adb pull /data/anr/anr_2018-06-24-01-41-39-700 .
adb: error: failed to copy '/data/anr/anr_2018-06-24-01-41-39-700' to './anr_2018-06-24-01-41-39-700': remote open failed: Permission denied

marlin:/data/anr $ ls -al
total 1184
drwxrwxr-x  2 system system   4096 2018-06-24 13:57 .
drwxrwx--x 43 system system   4096 1970-02-11 19:30 ..
-rw-------  1 system system 503517 2018-06-24 01:41 anr_2018-06-24-01-41-39-700
-rw-------  1 system system 683519 2018-06-24 13:57 anr_2018-06-24-13-57-19-517
marlin:/data/anr $ cp anr_2018-06-24-13-57-19-517 /sdcard/Download
cp: /sdcard/Download/anr_2018-06-24-13-57-19-517: Permission denied
```

I googled many times and didn't find a solution and i'm really going to be crazy. Any help or hint will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried "adb pull data/anr/anr_xxx" ??

Comment: @Chandrakanth. Yeah, please see the 7th line in the quoted text in my question post, that's the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `adb bugreport ./bugreport.zip`, then unzip bugreport.zip, you will find a `bugreporp-xxx.txt`. from this txt, you can get /data/anr/anr_xxx file content by greping `/data/anr/anr_`

Comment: I try this idea, but still failed.    `Error unlinking temporary trace path /data/anr/dumptrace_xNqWs7: Permission denied
execvp on command 'parse_radio_log /proc/last_radio_log' failed (error: Permission denied)`